# What options for specifying IP addresses exist in VSphere compared with NSX?

Tags: vmware-vsphere, ipam

What knobs are available for configuring the IP Addresses of VMs in vsphere, without NSX, as compared to *with* NSX?  I see in my VSphere clusters that

- VMs have multiple IPs
- These presumeably are randomly assigned by a DHCP host somehow

Is there a way to influence or lock down a specific IP for a VM in vsphere, or should we use nSX for this kind of behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

You can assign ip addressing configuration to virtual machines the same as you would for physical machines; either static assignments or DHCP assignments. NSX isn't required.

Comment: for IPAM and IP subnet management - how is this handled with vsphere ?  Presumably it creates its own subnet and tracks it somehow ?